# How to fix ' Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") ' while trying to webscrape using rvest

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, rstudio, rvest

I'm a R beginner and I'm trying to write a function to scrape all the song lyrics from a certain singer from a website, returning a tibble with the lyrics and the name of the song. I already managed to get all the songs links, but I'm stuck trying to write a function to actually get the lyrics.

website in question is: https://www.letras.mus.br/belchior/44457/

selector for the song title: `#js-lyric-cnt > article > div.cnt-head.cnt-head--l > div.cnt-head_title > h1`

selector for the song lyrics: `#js-lyric-cnt > article > div.cnt-letra-trad.g-pr.g-sp > div.cnt-letra.p402_premium`

I wrote this function:

```
get_lyrics <- function(url){
  url %>% read_html() %>% 
    um <- html_nodes('#js-lyric-cnt > article > div.cnt-letra-trad.g-pr.g-sp > div.cnt-letra.p402_premium')  
    um %>% 
    lyrics <- html_text()
  url %>% read_html() %>%
    dois <- html_nodes('#js-lyric-cnt > article > div.cnt-head.cnt-head--l > div.cnt-head_title > h1') 
    dois %>% 
    title <- html_text()
  data_frame(title, lyrics)
}
```

But when I try to run I get:

```
 get_lyrics('https://www.letras.mus.br/belchior/1391391/')
 Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I'm not sure what I can do to fix it so I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten your selectors (generally faster and more stable). `read_html` only once then work with the retrieved content. I assume (eek) - you want a dataframe with 1 entry for the title and 1 corresponding entry for the lyrics. The lyrics are within `p` tags within parent element with class `cnt-letra`; furthermore, individual lyric lines are `br` tag separated. In order to preserve a sense of the original lyrics line spacing when parsing to a single string I add '\n' to account for these breaks.

I got the functions necessary to work around the lack of `br` handling in `rvest` from @rentrop [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest/issues/175) - though as that issue is quite old perhaps I have missed the addition of this feature?

Be careful about the sequencing you use when chaining methods to ensure the flow is as intended.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

html_text_collapse <- function(x, trim = FALSE, collapse = "\n"){
  UseMethod("html_text_collapse")
}

html_text_collapse.xml_nodeset <- function(x, trim = FALSE, collapse = "\n"){
  vapply(x, html_text_collapse.xml_node, character(1), trim = trim, collapse = collapse)
}

html_text_collapse.xml_node <- function(x, trim = FALSE, collapse = "\n"){
  paste(xml2::xml_find_all(x, ".//text()"), collapse = collapse)
}


get_lyrics <- function(url){
    page <- read_html(url)
    lyrics <- toString(page %>% html_nodes('.cnt-letra p') %>% html_text_collapse) 
    title <- page %>% html_node('.cnt-head_title') %>% html_text()
    return(data.frame(title, lyrics))
}

get_lyrics('https://www.letras.mus.br/belchior/44457/')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to just get the lyrics you can use the `genius` package.

`genius::genius_lyrics("Belchior", "Na Hora do Almoco")` will fetch the lyrics.